# Filtering content of UITableView using predicate

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, core-data

I have a table populating from CoreData and I want to filter based on a boolean property. If the place is marked as a favourite I want display the place in the tableview. The code is as follows:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return  [self.clubs count];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AppDelegate *del = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.type = del.type;
    self.searchTxt = del.searchTxt;
    //Core data fetch
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[SDCoreDataController sharedInstance] backgroundManagedObjectContext];
    if(!self.clubs){
        self.clubs = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    }
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Place"];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [sortDescriptor release];

    [managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        self.clubs = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    }];   

    if (self.clubs == nil) {
        // Handle the error
    }

}




- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    NSPredicate *predicate;
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"favourite == 0"];
    NSArray *myArray2 = [self.clubs filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    Place * place = [myArray2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    PlaceListCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[PlaceListCustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero ]autorelease];
    }



    UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"table_row_bg.png"]];

    cell.backgroundColor = background;

    [background release];
    // Configure the cell
    cell.placeName.text = place.name;
    cell.townName.text = place.addressline2;
    cell.type.text = place.type;
    cell.disclosure.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"disclosure_icon.png"];
    if(place.promo ==[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]){
        cell.promotag.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"promo_tag.png"];
    }
    cell.reviewNumber.text = @"0 Reviews";
    cell.reviewView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rating_3.png"];
    //Check if there is an image. If not, set the default image
    if (place.image != nil) 
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:place.image];

    }
    else 
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no-image-available.jpg"];    
    }

    return cell;

}
@end
```

This current method is broken due to the the predicate I tried to add in the cellForRow and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should set up your data array in such a way that it is already ordered correctly for display in your table view.

Better, you should use an `NSFetchedResultsController` which is much more memory efficient and less error prone.

You should not manipulate or filter your data array in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. This is very unlikely to work and certain to be massively inefficient.

*And please, do not just dump irrelevant code into the question.*